# передача параметров в обработчик ответа JQuery .get

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.
Отправляю запрос на сервер при помощи JQuery, получаю ответ. Но не могу понять как при обработке использовать параметры вызывающей функции.

```
var someVar =   "test";
$.get('url.html',{'query':'someQuery').success(function(data){
    console.log(someVar); // Как сюда передать значение переменной?
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может так?

```
var someVar = "test";
var url = "url.html";
var sendData = {"query": "someQuery"};

$.get(url, sendData).success(function (data) {
    console.log(someVar);
    console.log(url);
    console.log(sendData);

    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: :D К ночи голова совсем не варит видимо. Вы мне подсказали решение. Моя переменная это this инпута, инициализировавшего событие, достаточно его запихать в переменную. и она будет в зоне видимости .get

Comment: var self = this; $.get(url, sendData).success(function (data) {console.log(self)}); ))